# Best way to refactor code that just uses a different version of an imported function

Tags: python, refactoring

I have some code which is similar to the code below

```
import food.data.dairy.taste_extract as dairy_extract
import food.data.fruit.taste_extract as fruit_extract
import food.data.vegetable.taste_extract as vegetable_extract


def get_taste(food):
    """
    Depending on what the food type is, use the category 
    specific function to get the taste of that particular food
    """
    if food.type == 'dairy':
        taste = dairy_extract(food)
    elif food.type == 'fruit':
        taste = fruit_extract(food)
    elif food.type == 'vegetable':
        taste = vegetable_extract(food)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError 
    
    return taste
```

Basically I am trying to return the taste of the given food. Depending on the food type, there is custom logic in the functions imported at the top of the script that will return the taste of that particular food. Assume that the particular logic in those functions is not necessarily similar enough to wrap them into a single function. I'm wondering what are some of the best ways I might refactor this to make it cleaner. In my real use case I have not 3 IF statements (and imports), but ~10 and growing so it's quite a lot of IF statements and a lot of imports at the top of this file. I know I can replace the IF-ELSE statements with a dictionary mapping like this `mapping = {'dairy':dairy_extract, 'vegetable':vegetable_extract, 'fruit': fruit_extract}` and then get `taste = mapping[food.type]`, but that still leaves a lot of ugly imports at the top. Is there a good/common way of refactoring this so as to reduce the number of imports at the top of this file and reduce the number of IF-ELSE statements at the same time?

Comment: Are all of your imports in the same format, ie. `food.data.something.taste_extract`? Have you considered refactoring these into classes with methods?

Comment: That would actually be an elegant solution for this problem, although in the actual case I'm working with would entail a major refactor of all sorts of complicated code. But, in hindsight, that might have been a nice way to have organized this code base, and would clean up a number of other issues not mentioned here.